# Unix - extract a word from a string

Tags: unix, awk, grep

need some help with unix scripting

My file looks like below :

```
certificate: DPCert_CryptoCer [up]
certificate: ELABpreprod_CA1V2_CER [up]
certificate: ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER [up]
certificate: ELABpreprod_PUBROOT_CER [up]
certificate: hbosIssuerCert [up]
certificate: hbosRootCert [up]
certificate: MQ_CryptoCer [up]
```

my script should output the below only into a file:

```
DPCert_CryptoCer
ELABpreprod_CA1V2_CER
ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER 
ELABpreprod_PUBROOT_CER
hbosIssuerCert 
hbosRootCert
MQ_CryptoCer
```

Any help with sed / awk / grep  would be appreciated .

Comment: -1: because providing a single example of desired output is not equivalent to asking a question.  Describe the problem ("I want to output the 2nd column") and the solution is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the 2nd field, use:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file
DPCert_CryptoCer
ELABpreprod_CA1V2_CER
ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER
ELABpreprod_PUBROOT_CER
hbosIssuerCert
hbosRootCert
MQ_CryptoCer
```

If it is the penultimate field what you need, use:

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file
DPCert_CryptoCer
ELABpreprod_CA1V2_CER
ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER
ELABpreprod_PUBROOT_CER
hbosIssuerCert
hbosRootCert
MQ_CryptoCer
```

To save the content into another file, do redirect the command:

```
awk '{print $2}' file > new_file
```

or

```
awk '{print $(NF-1)}' file > new_file
```

---

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=certificate: )[^[]*' file
DPCert_CryptoCer 
ELABpreprod_CA1V2_CER 
ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER 
ELABpreprod_PUBROOT_CER 
hbosIssuerCert 
hbosRootCert 
MQ_CryptoCer
```

It prints everything after `certificate:` and up to the `[` character.

Comment: If i want to print only "ELABpreprod_CA2V2"  from ELABpreprod_CA2V2_CER, How do we use awk here?

Comment: @EashwarGadanchi you use `cut`: `cut -d_ -f-2`

Answer (score 1):

try sed

```
sed -r 's/.* (.*) .*/\1/' file
```

if the fields are separated by an empty character, and you want to get the 2nd field, you can use cut

```
cut -d' ' -f2 file
```